# Best strucutre for Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I want to distribute info on sharepoint to differenct groups A,B, and C and I want only the content for group A to be seen by group A, only the content for gorup B to be seen by gorup B, and only the content for gorup c to be seen by gorup C.

What is the best way to structure a Sharepoint team site?

Currently I have

team/sites/groupA
team/sites/groupB
team/sites/groupC

and I was going to set up 3 sharepoint groups for A,B and C and permission the three sites to the 3 sharepoint groups.

But can/should it be set up with only 1 site like:

team/sites/MainSite

and then all the permissions managed using inherited permissions etc...

I am a sharepoint beginner and don't know much about the inheritied permissions or heirarchy of how a single site would work. Any thougths on which way is better? I would like to make the site or sites as easy to maintain as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have desgined it as site collection is best approach. the best approach is if you need fine grained permission for a site create a site collection.
Although regarding your other question of having main site and then having sub-site it would not be possible using inheriting permission, you would have to use fine grained permission if you want to give diffrent permission for each subsite.
if the gr
although you could have done it by stop inheriting permission but it should be only done when you know the groups a ,b & c would be having small number of users